# How to set data into table after selecting in select2 jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Can I ask for help? 
I want to get the data based from the selected item in select2 box and then put it into a table column. I'm using jquery and laravel.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? Any code? Please, take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Right now, i figured out how to get the id of the selected item in select2 box.
Here's the sample code:

`$('#add_row').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    newRow = 
     '<tr><td style="width:45%"><select class="products form-control form-control-sm" style="width:100%"><option> </option></select></td></tr>';
        $.ajax({
         ________
           });
        });    
      table.prepend(newRow);
   });
        **$('tbody').delegate('.products', 'select2:selecting', function(){
        alert("select2 id: " + $(this).val());**
});`

Comment: so, answer your question with the solution that you've found

Comment: I already found a solution. However, I cannot fetch the data into the column field.